# How to echo variables using cat into file?

Tags: bash, shell, cat, here-document

I have simple script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

BOO=bla-bla-bla

cat > ./Makefile <<'EOF'
        Hello
        INCLUDES := -I/data/opt/include/ -Ideps/ -I$BOO/include
EOF
```

Yet it outputs into file:

```
 Hello
 INCLUDES := -I/data/opt/include/ -Ideps/ -I$BOO/include
```

how to make `cat` use my variables values, not names inside that string?

Answer (score 14):

Drop the single quotes around the here-document limit string `EOF` to avoid suppressing parameter substitution. More details [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Especially take note of *"[Example 19-7. Parameter substitution turned off](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html#HEREESC)"* and *"[Example 19-8. A script that generates another script](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html#HERELIT)"*.

Comment: @sukminder, thank you. Will keep this in mind going forward