# Unexpected token within environment variable throws syntax error in cloud-init

Tags: bash, rhel, cloud-init

> **What specific syntax must be changed in the code below in order to prevent the error that is being thrown when an environment variable contains an unexpected token?**

**THE CODE:**

Specifically, a cloud-init startup script running in an RHEL 7 VM in Azure needs to switch to run as a non-root user while running a short sequence of specific commands including the following line which passes the values of environmental variables into `az login`:

```
su - azureuser << EOF
echo "User from whoami is: "
whoami
echo "About to login to az.  "
az login --service-principal -u \"$AZ_CLIENT\" -p \"$AZ_PASS\" --tenant \"$AZ_TENANT\"
EOF
```

Note that the `su - azureuser << EOF...EOF` is used in the cloud-init script in order to ensure that the commands contained between the `EOF` delimiters are executed as the specified non-root user.

**THE ERROR:**

The error being thrown seems to be caused by a parenthetic symbol that is part of a random password that populates the `$AZ_PASS` variable.  We changed the password below to a fake password for security, but we the following retains the `(` symbol to illustrate the error:

```
azure-arm: User from whoami is:
azure-arm: azureuser
azure-arm: About to login to az.
azure-arm: -bash: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
azure-arm: -bash: line 4: `az login --service-principal -u \"client-id-long-string\" -p \"gy75k9([0y6se2v^\" --tenant \"long-tenant-id-string\"'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape the double quotes in a here-doc. The way you have it there, the outer shell expands the variables, and the shell started by `su` sees `-p \"gy75k9([0y6se2v^\"` literally, the backslashes escape the quotes, and the `(` is unquoted.

Without the backslashes, it should work as long as the password doesn't contain `\`, `$`, `"` or backtick. Or change to single quotes so you only need to care about single quotes in the password.

```
su - azureuser << EOF
...
az login --service-principal -u '$AZ_CLIENT' -p '$AZ_PASS' --tenant '$AZ_TENANT'
EOF
```

See [Escape a variable for use as content of another script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379181/escape-a-variable-for-use-as-content-of-another-script) about dealing with arbitrary values, including the single quotes.

---

Alternatively, have the shell started by `su` expand the variables. You'll need to quote the here-doc delimiter (or all the `$` signs in the here-doc), and use`su -p` to have the environment variables preserved past `su`. And this time, double-quotes are needed, to allow the inner shell to expand the variables.

```
export AZ_CLIENT AZ_PASS AZ_TENANT
su -p - azureuser << 'EOF'
...
az login --service-principal -u "$AZ_CLIENT" -p "$AZ_PASS" --tenant "$AZ_TENANT"
EOF
```

Comment: The answer to [this other OP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94664/how-to-echo-variables-using-cat-into-file) , and particularly the contents of [this other link](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) enabled us to resolve a related problem without having to post another question on this site.